# Taking arguments from windows run in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to pass some arguments from the windows run while calling a powershell script. Looks something like this:
myscript "Some parameters", "some other"
Is this even possible? If so, how can I take the arguments from it to the powershell script and use them?
So far I got how you can ask for a user input parameter via cmd using the "ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName" option of the Parameter but it's not what I want.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell essentially provides two ways for handling script arguments:

- The [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#args) `$args` holds a list of all arguments, which can then be accessed by index:

  Script:

  ```
  "1st argument: " + $args[0]
  "2nd argument: " + $args[1]
  "3rd argument: " + $args[2]
  ```

  Invocation:

  ```
  powershell.exe -File .\script.ps1 "foo" "bar"
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  1st argument: foo
  2nd argument: bar
  3rd argument:
  ```
- A [`Param()` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) at the beginning of the script gets the parameter values assigned to individual variables:

  Script:

  ```
  Param(
    [Parameter()]$p1 = '',
    [Parameter()]$p2 = '',
    [Parameter()]$p3 = ''
  )

  "1st argument: " + $p1
  "2nd argument: " + $p2
  "3rd argument: " + $p3
  ```

  Invocation:

  ```
  powershell.exe -File .\script.ps1 "foo" "bar"
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  1st argument: foo
  2nd argument: bar
  3rd argument:
  ```

If you want to be able to invoke a PowerShell script without explicitly running the `powershell.exe` command you need to change the default action for the `Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1` type in the registry, though. You probably also need to adjust the execution policy on your system(s) (`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`).

Typically you'd use `$args` only for very simple scenarios (a handful arguments in well-defined order). A full parameter definition gives you far better control about the parameter handling (you can make parameters optional or mandatory, define parameter types, define default values, do validation, etc.).

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I barely understand your question. Here's an attempt to get closer to what you want..

You attempt to call a powershell script through the Windows CMD, like so:

```
powershell.exe myscript.ps1 parameter1 parameter2 anotherparameter
```

The above is how you can take unnamed parameters.
You could also look into named parameters, like so:

```
Powershell.exe myscript.ps1 -param1 "Test" -param2 "Test2" -anotherparameter "Test3"
```

You can in the CMD Accept input from a user using "Set", like so:

```
set /p id="Enter ID: "
```

In powershell you would use Read-host, like so:

```
$answer = Read-Host "Please input the answer to this question"
```

Comment: Further reading on named parameters: http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-best-practice-2-use-named-parameters-not-positional-and-partial-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your script you declare the parameters you want to pass, here is an example from my build.ps1

```
param (
    [string] $searchTerm,
    [ValidateSet('Remote', 'Local')][string] $sourceType = 'local',
    [switch] $force
)

Write-Host $searchTerm
```

You can then pass your parameters either by the order:

```
build.ps1 '1234' local -force
```

or with named paramters

```
build.ps1 -searchTerm '1234' -sourceType local -force
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. Maybe I missed something